# Apex errors with Custom button to add existing records on a custom object

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, custom-button

I am receiving apex errors with the following code:

```
public with sharing class AddExistingSpecsExt {

    public Specifications__c loadedSpec { get; private set; }

public AddExistingSpecsExt() {
    String specId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    if (String.isBlank(specId)) return;

    List<Specifications__c> candidates = [
        SELECT Id, Name, Product__c FROM Specifications__c WHERE Id = :specId LIMIT 1
    ];
    if (!candidates.isEmpty()) loadedSpec = candidates[0];
}
    public PageReference associate () {

        Specifications__c candidates = new Specifications__c ( Id = Specifications__c.Product__c, Name = Specifications__c.Id);

        try {
            Database.update(candidates);
        } catch (Exception error) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Error while associating.' + error.getMessage()));
        }

        PageReference page = new PageReference('/' + candidates);

        return page.setRedirect(true);
    }

    public PageReference cancel () {
        PageReference page = new PageReference('/' + Null);
        return page.setRedirect(true);        
    }

}
```

Attempting to add records to a related list through a custom button and small vf page.

The Error is Line 16

> Invalid initial expression type for field Specifications__c.Id, expecting: Id

Any help?

Comment: `Name = Specifications__c.Id` instead `Name=loadedSpec.Id`  also `Specifications__c.Product__c` should be `loadedSpec.Product__c`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing `data` and `metadata`. So instead of getting a value, you are getting `SObjectField`.

```
Id data = loadedSpec.Id;
SObjectField metadata = Spefications__c.Id;
```

You need to use the *former* (`data`) in your code:

```
Schema.SObjectField idMetadata = Specifications__c.Id; // you don't need this
Id idData = loadedSpec.Id;

SObjectField productMetadata = Specifications__c.Product__c; // you don't need this
String productData = loadedSpec.Product__c;

Specifications__c record = new Specifications__c(Id=idData, Name=productData);
```

Also, you don't even need to instantiate a new `Specifications__c` record at all. Just do:

```
loadedSpec.Name = loadedSpec.Product__c;
//update logic
```

One last note, you should `return null` in your `catch` block after calling `ApexPages.addMessage`.

Comment: Whoa, going over my head now. Where would I put the former and fix the SObject vs SObjectType issue?

Comment: @Jason Check the updated answer.

Comment: I have no idea whats going on now. I dont have a Schema.SObjectField = Specifications__c.id; in my code.

Comment: You just aren't declaring it...but you do have it in your code. That's the `value` you're trying to assign in your `key=value` pairs in your `Specifications__c` constructor at the start of `associate`.

Comment: You want the data and not the metadata of the object. That is what he is trying to say;

Comment: Thanks @karthikselva, that distinction is much better than the one I had.

Comment: I haven't seen any specific use of retrieving the metadata like this, but its really good one to know.  Your answer has great depth on the code, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you are assigning the ID into a Name field and a lookup (I assume it's a lookup) into the ID field.... but that could be the correct logic...

`Specifications__c candidates = new Specifications__c ( Id = Specifications__c.Product__c, Name = Specifications__c.Id);`

If `Product__c` is not an ID field, you will get an error.

Comment: see Adrian's answer for an explanation on how to use a variable vs the actual sObject